# REST api to retrieve user profiles (Spring Boot)

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, rest

I want to display list of freelancers with there data and profile image.
How to write a rest api to retrieve list of profile images?

Or should I retrieve list of user data and retrieve there images one by one

I have created api to retrieve a single image

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/{userName}/retrieveImage")
    public ResponseEntity<?> retrieveImage(@PathVariable String userName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        byte[] imageData;
        imageData = freelancerService.retrieveImageFromFileSystem(userName);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(imageData, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: You can return the image URL (String), and then show this image where you need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your url name is not good case for rest endpoint naming. You can check a good documentation for that:

[Rest Api Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design)

So it should be something like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/images/image/{userName}")
```

Instead of `userName`, use `userId` or similar to that which you can use it for database search with index and more suitable for unique identification for requests.

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(value = "/images/image/{userName}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> retrieveImage(@PathVariable String userName) throws IOException {
   InputStream inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(pathOfImageFile);
   // This method can return inputStream
   // freelancerService.retrieveImageFromFileSystem(userName);
   return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(ininputStream, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```